# Bulma - force navbar vertical on desktop

Tags: html, css, navigation, bulma

With bulma I want to create a site that follows sports (baseball, basketball ... tennis, wrestling) but by the time I get to the end (alphabetically it's wrestling) there are too many items (horizontally left to right) for a navbar to show properly on a desktop. So I thought I could use a menu (vertical navigation) but it doesn't give me a hamburger icon or anything similar on a mobile device. I used the menu example [found here](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/menu/). I thought to use navbar on mobile and menu for desktops via media queries with something along the lines of

```
/** mobile **/
@media (max-width: 768px) {

      .menu {
       display: none;
      }
}

/** desktop **/
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1215px) {

    .navbar {
     display: none;
    }
}
```

but that still leaves me with two separate components & lists of links, icons, etc.. Is there a way to force the bulma navbar to remain vertical all the time? That way I can use just one component instead of two...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you. I wanted a sidebar that I could use as my main menu, with a hamburger when displaying in responsive mode.

So I overrode the  component from Bulma (which is the side menu):

- I use the SASS version of Bulma
- I added an `extensions` folder within the Bulma build
- I added my `improved_sidebar.sass` file in it

Here's my code, which might be helpful to you:

```
// ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
// Aside improvements
// ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
$aside-width: 250px
$aside-right-padding: 30px
$aside-delta: $aside-width - $aside-right-padding
aside
    display: block
    box-sizing: border-box
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    left: 0
    max-width: $aside-width
    height: 100%
    padding:
        top: 10px
        bottom: 10px
        left: 10px
        right: $aside-right-padding
    overflow-y: auto

    // Initially hidden in mobile mode. Needs to be flagged as "is-active" to be shown
    // It will appear OVER the page content
    +touch
        left: -$aside-delta

        &.is-active
            left: 0
            z-index: 900



// ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
// Clickable burger in mobile mode
// ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
$burger-dimensions: 25px
#aside-burger
    display: none

    +touch
        position: absolute
        display: block
        top: calc(50% - calc(#{$burger-dimensions} / 2))
        right: calc(calc(#{$aside-right-padding} - #{$burger-dimensions}) / 2)
        width: $burger-dimensions
        height: $burger-dimensions
        color: white

    i
        position: relative
        z-index: 1000
        font-size: 40px !important
        cursor: pointer

        &:hover
            color: $info

        &:active
            color: $danger


// Rotate the icon when the sidebar is toggled
aside.is-active
    i
        transform: rotate(180deg)


// ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
// Utilities
// ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
// The sidebar is natively visible only in desktop
// Therefore we move tagged items to the right, of the same amount
.adjust-with-sidebar
    +touch
        margin-left: $aside-right-padding

    +desktop
        margin-left: $aside-width
```

And here is my HTML template for the  (I'm using `jinja2` and `vuejs` for templating):

```html
{% load static %}

<aside class="menu" :class="{'is-active': activeSidebar}">
    <div id="aside-burger" @click="activeSidebar = !activeSidebar">
        <span class="icon" >
            <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <figure class="image has-text-centered">
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">
            <img id="menu-logo" src="/media/core/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>
    </figure>
    <p class="menu-label">Exemples</p>
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li><a id="example" href="{% url 'example' %}">API Exemple</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="menu-label">Mon Compte</p>
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li><a id="account-info" href="{% url 'user_account' %}">Mes informations</a></li>
        <li><a id="logout" @click.prevent="submitLogoutForm">Déconnexion</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could force the navbar to be vertical instead of using a menu bar because menu bars in Bulma are vertical and don't actually expand or compress with burgers (navbars use burgers). So, check out this post by [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_vertical_menu.asp) where they talk about forcing the navbar vertically with CSS. Also, Bulma's navbars fit across the whole screen when you open them up with the navbar burger. This is a characteristic of Bulma so I'm not sure if you want it that way - you may have to tweak some CSS here and there.